# Referring to another sheet's cell depending on the value of another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not quite sure how to word it, but I'm currently doing a project on excel. So far I have the invoice sheet containing the customer number and pricing etc etc, and another to contain all customer information such as their home and email address and phone numbers in order of their customer number.

I am currently trying to have a formula automatically add the name of the customer depending on the number entered in the invoice. By this, I mean that when I enter a number in the column, it will refer to the customer spread sheet and retrieve the name. But I'm not sure how I will do this.

The only thing that comes to my head, is that logically it would be something like '=Customers!B(D3)', where D3 is the customer number. I would have thought that it would get the value of D3, and say D3 contains the number 3 then it will go to cell B3 in sheet Customers.

I'm not sure how to do this, so is there some sort of GetValue function? I mainly code Java so am fairly new to Excel.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thanks :)

Comment: VBA? Like I said, very new sorry, haha

Comment: Formula is the way to go for this.  Check out `VLookUp`

Comment: I have tried the formula '=VLOOKUP(C7,Customers!A3:B13,2,TRUE)' in my Invoice spreadsheet, which returns N/A. I have not had much time to look into VLOOPUP, and have to go so I will continue to try tomorrow. Just posting this here incase I'm doing something obviously wrong. (Although as you don't have the spreadsheet it may be difficult to interpret)

Comment: To do exactly what you are asking, is not advised but it would be using the INDIRECT function you could write `=INDIRECT("Customers!B" & D3)` any cell you type this is will have the same value as the cell in Column B of Sheet Customers where the Row is the number found in cell D3 of the active sheet. But as stated earlier You are probably looking for a VLOOKUP function.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(C7,Customers!A3:B13,2,TRUE)` This should return the value in column B where the value in Column A is equal to the value C7 on your active worksheet.

Comment: Indirect function doesn't look preferable, as this is likely to be in changing order each time, and there will be several similar spreadsheets all referring to the Customer sheet, which will be changing all the time. (Hypothetically at least)

Comment: If your customer numbers are not sorted, you'll need to specify FALSE as the 4th argument to VLOOKUP. TRUE means you promise it's a sorted list, which (A) permits a more efficient search (I haven't benchmarked but I assume O(log n) vs O(n) -- a noticeable difference on large data sets) and (B) allows searching for values which fall between values in list. FALSE means a sequential search for an exact match. BTW, I personally prefer using MATCH as an argument to INDEX instead of VLOOKUP -- as a JAVA programmer you might appreciate that more-flexible, easier-to-debug, albeit more verbose syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few different functions you could use for this but the best would be `INDEX`

To get the value in Column B use `=Index(Customers!B1:H100,D3,1)`

Column C `=Index(Customers!B1:H100,D3,2)`

The first argument is the range, second argument is row position, and third position is column position.

Here is [some documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/index-HP005209138.aspx) to read